# Germanium diode 455KHz AM detector

Tags: amplitude-modulation, vintage

Germanium diodes were used for AM detection for many decades before silicon diodes became cheap. They were attractive when compared to the large power hungry valves.

Nowadays, silicon diodes are much cheaper and easier to find than germanium diodes, so they are commonly used for detector service.

The old school point contact germanium diode has low capacitance, low foward drop, and more gradual VI characteristics which should give low distortion.

I have seen germanium diodes on some high end MW AM tuners.

Prebiasing the diodes and keeping the output voltage level reasonably high does result in low distortion.

My question is about impedence level.

If the impedence is low, like say 5K, the bulk resistance is significant. This could be why old solid state radios sound bad. If the impedence is too high then the diode leakage currents will at some point muck things up. Remember that leakage is very temperature dependant and not linear.

1 meg (which is common for valve stuff) sounds much better.

- Is 1 meg too high for germanium considering leakage issues?
- What impedence would be optimum?
- Would the valve stuff do better with a properly prebiased silicon diode circuit which has much less leakage?

Comment: *The old school point contact germanium diode has low capacitance, low foward drop, and more gradual VI characteristics which should give low distortion.* Compared to what? To a silicon Schottky diode? Don't think so. *I have seen germanium diodes on some high end MW AM tuners.* And I've seen gold-plated connectors for digital audio... that's not really an argument!

Answer (score 1):

I think your current should be 100x the leakage current to be under 1% distortion.  More would be better as long as you are not significantly heating the diode which causes more problems.

Answer (score 0):

At 1mA Ibias, Rdiode is 26 ohms. At 1uamp Ibiase, Rdiode is 26,000 ohms.

Where do you need to operate?

Comment: .I think closer to the 1 microamp point ,I have used a prebiased fullwave detector running off an old school double tuned 455KHz IFT that has no taps .The point contact Ge diode has bulk resistance as well as erbus moll .What you have pointed out is interesting because it implies that impedence does not matter ,But if I tapped down to get Lo Z then I would be worse off .